# Replace unknown sub-string in an URL

Tags: regex, string, bash

I have an URL in the format like `https://foo.bar.whoo.dum.io`, for which I like to replace the `foo` string with something else. Of course, the `foo` part is unknown and can be anything.

I tried with a simple regex like `(.+?)\.(.+)`, but it seems that regex in Bash is always greedy (or?).

My best attempt is to split the string by `.` and then join it back with the first part left out, but I was wondering, whether there is a more intuitive, different solution.

Thank you

Comment: What about: https://regex101.com/r/vnBXib/1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of ways of getting the desired output.

If you're sure the url will always start with `https://`, we can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove everything before the first `.` and then add the replacement you need:

```sh
input="https://foo.bar.whoo.dum.io"

echo "https://new.${input#*.}"
```

Will output

```
https://new.bar.whoo.dum.io
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzOvoLTEVimjpKSg2EpfPy0/Xy8psUivPAPISCnN1cvMV@LiSk3OyFeAq8lLLddTqQZrVNbSq1X6/x8A)

Comment: Nice one. People tend to forget about parameter expansion in Bash and go for external binaries like `sed`, `cut`, and `awk` based solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed`:

```sh
url='https://foo.bar.whoo.dum.io'
url=$(sed 's,\(.*://\)[^/.]*,\1new_value,' <<< "$url")
```

Here, the sed command means:

- `\(.*://\)` - Capturing group 1: any text and then `://`
- `[^/.]*` -  zero or more chars other than `/` and `.`
- `\1new_value` - replaces the match with the Group 1 and `new_value` is appended to this group value.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/tDC4rz):

```sh
url='https://foo.bar.whoo.dum.io'
sed 's,\(.*://\)[^/.]*,\1new_value,' <<< "$url"
# => https://new_value.bar.whoo.dum.io
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Using Parameter expansion capability of bash here, adding this solution. Where `newValue` is variable with new value which you want to have in your url.

```
url='https://foo.bar.whoo.dum.io'
newValue="newValue"
echo "${url%//*}//$newValue.${url#*.}"
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `sed` code here. Where variable `url` has your shown sample url value in it.

```
echo "$url" | sed 's/:\/\/[^.]*/:\/\/new_value/'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, printing shell variable named `url` value by `echo` command and sending it as a standard input to `sed` command. Then in `sed` command using its capability of substitution here. Where substituting `://` just before1st occurrence of `.` with `://new_value` as per requirement.